# What is the most reliable way to hide elements and fade them in purely with CSS transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I want to hide an HTML element when the page loads, then fade it in with a CSS transition. My plan is to set the opacity to 0, and then use a CSS animation to transform it to 1.
But I am worried that the content will remain hidden in old browsers that can't handle CSS transitions. 
Is there a safer way to hide the content? Or to exclude this code from browsers that can't handle it?

Answer (score 0):

As always, your problem is with older versions of IE.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

I'm a big believer in progressive enhancement amd handling things CSS only.

Using Javascript could provide fallback for older browser or using libraries like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) but I hate these kind of solutions and they come with there own problems. What if the visitor has JS disabled?

Luckily we can safely let older browser ignore the fade in animation. Just set opacity on 1 for the default div you want to fade in and start the keyframe animation at opacity set to 0.

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeIn 7s ease infinite;
 }
@keyframes fadeIn {
     0% { opacity: 0; }
     50% { opacity: 1; }
     100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3rzL0xz8/